# Using groupby and aggregate creates an empty row on top of the first data row that I can't seem to select

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the starting data table:

```
Organ     1000.1     2000.1     3000.1     4000.1    ....
a         333        34343      3434       23233
a         334        123324     1233       123124
a         33         2323       232        2323
b         3333        4444      333         34444
b         33333       3333      333        33333
.
.
.
```

and so on. The numbers are just random numbers, and the values of the Organ column contain some duplicates as you can see.

I am trying to calculate count, mean, and std so that I can compute p-values like:

```
data = pd.read_excel('file')
data_stat = data.groupby(data.columns[0]).aggregate(['count','mean','std'])
```

This does compute the three parameters, but it does so with wrong format:

[image]

The above screenshot doesn't match the example data table but just wanted to show the outcome format. Tried using reset_index() but that didn't work:

[image]

Any suggestion on how I could get rid of the row with 'Organ' text in it (after removing the row, move everything up so there's no blank row)?

and I would also like to 'disassemble' the first row so it looks like:
[image]

Of course, if disassembling the first row isn't required to calculate p-values, then it isn't necessary. My final objective is to calculate p-values between all possible combinations of each row (like a vs b, a vs c, a vs d, a vs e, ... , b vs c, b vs d, etc.) for each column, which I have a feeling will be creating another post in the future if I get stuck again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get `MultiIndex` in columns and for change first column use:

```
df = data.groupby(data.columns[0]).aggregate(['count','mean','std']).reset_index()

L = [(a,b) if b!= '' else ('value', a)for a,b in df.columns.tolist()]
print (L)
[('value', 'Organ'), ('1000.1', 'count'), ('1000.1', 'mean'), ('1000.1', 'std'), 
 ('2000.1', 'count'), ('2000.1', 'mean'), ('2000.1', 'std'), ('3000.1', 'count'), 
 ('3000.1', 'mean'), ('3000.1', 'std'), ('4000.1', 'count'), ('4000.1', 'mean'), 
 ('4000.1', 'std')]

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(L)
print (df)
  value 1000.1                             2000.1                         \
  Organ  count          mean           std  count     mean           std   
0     a      3    233.333333    173.494476      3  53330.0  62695.216141   
1     b      2  18333.000000  21213.203436      2   3888.5    785.595634   

  3000.1                    4000.1                         
   count  mean          std  count     mean           std  
0      3  1633  1638.047924      3  49560.0  64560.464659  
1      2   333     0.000000      2  33888.5    785.595634
```

For display values of `MultiIndex` is possible use, check [`In [21]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object):

```
#temporaly display MultiIndex
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print (df)
      value 1000.1        1000.1        1000.1 2000.1   2000.1        2000.1  \
      Organ  count          mean           std  count     mean           std   
    0     a      3    233.333333    173.494476      3  53330.0  62695.216141   
    1     b      2  18333.000000  21213.203436      2   3888.5    785.595634   

      3000.1 3000.1       3000.1 4000.1   4000.1        4000.1  
       count   mean          std  count     mean           std  
    0      3   1633  1638.047924      3  49560.0  64560.464659  
    1      2    333     0.000000      2  33888.5    785.595634
```

---

Simpliest is avoid `MulitIndex` by flattening:

```
df = data.groupby(data.columns[0]).aggregate(['count','mean','std'])
df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  Organ  1000.1_count   1000.1_mean    1000.1_std  2000.1_count  2000.1_mean  \
0     a             3    233.333333    173.494476             3      53330.0   
1     b             2  18333.000000  21213.203436             2       3888.5   

     2000.1_std  3000.1_count  3000.1_mean   3000.1_std  4000.1_count  \
0  62695.216141             3         1633  1638.047924             3   
1    785.595634             2          333     0.000000             2   

   4000.1_mean    4000.1_std  
0      49560.0  64560.464659  
1      33888.5    785.595634
```

Comment: the flattening method does work to an extent, but would I be able to compute p-values of each column using count, mean, and std? And the first suggestion only does it for the first two rows, unless I can just add more row items to the line?

Comment: @BongKyoSeo - ok, then use first solution

Comment: the first solution doesn't seem to work, and it produces the same result as the second screenshot.

Comment: @BongKyoSeo - difference is in first column only

Comment: okay thanks for the help. Decided to simply edit the resulting excel file then resume the p-value calculations if possible :)